# Having issues trying to center an image using tailwinds containers - invisible padding to the right of the image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Why is my screenshot image not centered on the screen?

My css so far is this:

```
  <section class="hero container max-w-screen-lg mx-auto text-center pb-10">
      <div class="">
        <img src="/images/screenshot.png" alt="screenshot" width="887" height="550" />
      </div>
  </section>
```

When I inspect the image in chrome, I can see that there is some area on the right of the image that is not part of the image but is taking up space.

Here is a screenshot where you can see this invisible padding to the right of the image.

Any idea what is going on as I would like to understand how I can't even center a simple image.

As a bonus, if someone can figure this out using containers, can you also show me an alternate method using flex?  I tried 'flex items-center' also and that didn't work for me either.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me: 
<section class="grid place-items-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="screenshot" >
</section>

grid - Add the element a 'display: grid' css property
place-items-center - center value for the place-items css property

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `mx-auto` should also go to the image, tailwind make the image a block element:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="hero container max-w-screen-lg mx-auto pb-10">
    <img class="mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="screenshot" >
</section>
```

And with flexbox it should be `justify-center`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="hero container max-w-screen-lg mx-auto pb-10 flex justify-center">
    <img  src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="screenshot" >
</section>
```

Or `mx-auto` on the image:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.4.6/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="hero container max-w-screen-lg mx-auto pb-10 flex">
    <img class="mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="screenshot" >
</section>
```

Comment: for flex it says '.items-center' here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items/#app. why?

Comment: @Blankman this for vertical centring or cross axis if we consider the direction (it will center horizontally only if the direction is column). For the main axis it's justify-content (you will find it below in the Doc)

Comment: Some hero's don't wear capes